# Augmented Reality Toolkit - Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I have been searching around for free or commercial AR toolkits and need some advice on the best one!

I don't want to have one that recognises a pattern and creates a shape.  The idea I have uses the local location and uses POI's from a server to present them onto an AR view.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is this even remotely related?

Comment: Sorry i posted wrong thread.This was the real http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831071/how-to-detect-physical-object-in-android-augmented-reality

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you don't want one which recognizes shapes, writing one is fairly trivial. You need to detect the user's location, the camera orientation and then draw stuff on the camera. I made one for an app recently and it works quite well. Followed this tutorial:
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/42482

The guy also has written an AR kit. http://twitter.com/#!/androidarkit, http://code.google.com/p/androidarkit/

Comment: Ah. Damn. I just followed the tutorial. Some code seems to be there on github: http://github.com/haseman/Android-AR-Kit

Comment: Thanx for that info! I think I'll try the first link and I'll build my own "AR Viewer" as I don't need any shape recognition

Answer (score 6):

Looks like big players are starting to open free tools to embed an AR view into 3rd party applications.

- [Layar](http://site.layar.com/company/blog/the-easiest-way-to-add-augmented-reality-in-your-app/) announced a beta program (iPhone-only, and closed, but presumably this will result in an Android version in the coming weeks/months)
- [Qualcomm](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/news/7868707/Qualcomm-unveils-augmented-reality-platform-for-Google-Android-phones.html) announced an SDK for "fall"

Comment: Qualcomm has release a beta of their AR SDK for a contest http://developer.qualcomm.com/dev/augmented-reality

Comment: Wow thanks for the tips on Qualcomm - I was aware of Layar but hadn't seen that one... Looks pretty nifty...

Comment: Layar is not iPhone-only, it's currently Android, iPhone and Symbian.

Comment: Layar is pretty closed, you can only make Layars.  Also the Qualcomm SDK does not do location geo-based AR, only marker based

Comment: qualcomm sdk + skyhook = epic win. Layar uses skyhook.