# SDK for Augmented Reality for real world objects for Android?

Tags: android, andar

Is there any third party SDK for augmented reality of real word objects? I know of a few like QCAR from qualcomm and AndAR but these are tag based I am looking for an SDK which is not tag based and can find real world objects. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Before some days ago asked the same problem on Stack Overflow.But i came to know that till now its not possible to detect physical object directly with out generating any pattern.Dabhaid give me an answer.and we have long conversation so please go through it.May it help you

[Question And Discussion over same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831071/how-to-detect-physical-object-in-android-augmented-reality)

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are asking is related with AI.[Google Goggles](http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles/#text).application is some what similar to what you are asking. Link:

Answer (score 0):

There are other ones if you're not interested in tag/anchor based systems. There's one from [metaio](http://www.metaio.com/software/mobile-sdk/) and another from [mixare](http://www.mixare.org/).